# Importing CreateJS into an Angular project

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, createjs, easeljs

I'm trying to add CreateJS into an Angular project and not having much luck.

I'm not sure if CreateJS fully supports Typescript or ES6 modules. I could be wrong though. I'm using Angular CLI to set up the project and it's a clean setup with no other libraries.

If anyone smarter than me could take a look and explain how to get it installed that would be great.

---

**EDIT:**

I've got a version currently working by adding the library to the bottom of the index.html file. Doing it this way I also had to include `declare var createjs: any;` at the top of the relevant component.ts file in order for typescript to understand the createjs functions.

I don't think this is a final solution and I'm going to continue looking at how to load CreateJS properly.

Comment: You can just add it to your index.html manually. Sometimes this kind of monkey patch saves time.

Comment: Yeah that's worked. I'd still like to work out how to do it properly but at least I can get it up and running

Comment: @whoever-downvoted - an explanation of why you downvoted would be appreciated

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/issues/713

Comment: If you find how to do it properly, don't forget to put the solution here!